# owncloud add own filestorage

Tags: php, owncloud

I'm trying to hook owncloud into my cms. But I experience issues with the filestorage mounting. Does anyone have an example on how to create your own filestorage in an OwnCloud App.

I currently have the code below in a custom, active app (a different part allows to log CMS users to log in, which works):

```
class OC_Filestorage_HYN extends OC_Filestorage_Local {
    public function __construct($arguments) {
        global $SiteVisitor,$MultiSite;
        if( $SiteVisitor -> loggedin() && $SiteVisitor -> get_right( "owner" ) && defined("HYN_MS_DIR") && is_dir(HYN_MS_DIR) ) {
            $this -> datadir = HYN_MS_DIR;
        }
        return false;

    }
    public function mkdir($path){
        return false;
    }
    public function rmdir($path){
        return false;
    }
}

OC_Filesystem::clearMounts();
/**
*   @param 1: Class to handle Filestorage requests
*   @param 2: array of options
*   @param 3: mountpoint eg how to enter this storage in the view
*/
OC_Filesystem::mount( "OC_Filestorage_HYN" , array() , "/" );
```

Comment: I'm seeing that OC_FilesystemView helps in showing files outside of the default data dir.. But now what.

 * Apps that need to access files outside of the user data folders (to modify files
 * belonging to a user other than the one currently logged in, for example) should
 * use this class directly rather than using OC_Filesystem, or making use of PHP's
 * built-in file manipulation functions. This will ensure all hooks and proxies 
 * are triggered correctly.
 *
 * Filesystem functions are not called directly; they are passed to the correct 
 * OC_Filestorage object